# Not able to generate expected jmeter(4.0) report

Tags: .net, testing, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-4.0

I am new to jmeter. I need to perform performance testing in to different sites(one is old application and the other one is the new application).

Now for both I am taking the following configurations.Thread group:100 and 500;Ramp Up Time:1 and 500;Loop: 1.I am generating result after trying each combinations.

The configuration combinations I am trying are:

No of Users | Ramp Up Period| Loop
100               1            1
100              100           1
500               1            1
500              500           1

The exact steps I am following are:

1. First preparing scripts for the intended pages for both old and new application where No of threads:1,Ramp Up time:1,Loop:1.
2. Next running the whole script(with multiple pages) for both the applications with all the above configurations one by one.Generating report accordingly.
3. Next disabling all the pages but one for both old and new and generating reports accordingly.
4. Repeating step no 3 for all the pages.

According to our programming the new site should be faster than the old one(in terms of avg time,max time and min time).

Now the prob is under any configuration mentioned above,when we are running one page individually in both old and new applications it's working accordingly(Step 3 and 4).But when we try to give load to multiple pages at one go(Step 2).Suddenly old system performs faster than the new one.

I am a bit confused how to tackle this scenario.Also do we need to change ramp up times or we can keep it 0 or 1 for optimized load?

Note:The old application that we had was developed in Asp.net and now we are using MVC framework. I just want to generate a comparison report based on load ( load testing ) . For your information there is no chance in database and both the application are using the same database.

Comment: Can you give more details on what causing the delay? check server response time and if not, what are the network settings and timing